# Why does Task.Run() sometimes not seem to run tasks concurrently?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

I have a section of code that uses `Task.Run()` in an attempt to perform actions concurrently, but using the code to actually perform work causes the tasks to take as long as if they were run sequentially. Why would `Task.Run()` run tasks concurrently in some cases, and sequentially in others?

From reading other questions, I know that

```
public static void TestConcurrent()
{
  var task1 = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
  var task2 = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
  task1.Wait();
  task2.Wait();
}
```

will take about 1 second, despite 2 seconds of tasks being run. I have tested and verified this.

I have the following code:

```
public class TestObject
{
  public Dictionary<string, int> testDict = new();
  public List<string> testStrings;

  public TestObject(string path)
  {
    CustomArchive arc1 = new CustomArchive("path/to/archive");
    Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
      foreach ((string name, byte[] data) in arc1.Files)
      {
        testDict[name] = CustomType.FromBinary(data);
      }
    });

    CustomArchive arc2 = new CustomArchive("path/to/archive2");
    Task<List<string>> task2 = Task.Run(() => 
    {
      return arc2.Files
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains("SomeString"))
        .Select(kvp => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
          .GetString(kvp.Value)
        )
        .ToList();
    });

    testStrings = task2.Result;
    task1.Wait();
  }
}
```

I've tested the constructor using three different setups of this code, and received the following benchmark times:

- Using only code related to task1, including task1.Wait(): ~450ms
- Using only code related to task2, including task2.Result: ~350ms
- Using the entire constructor, as written: ~800ms
- Running the same code without tasks at all: ~800ms

Since I'm firing off the longer task first, and there are only two tasks, shouldn't the constructor take only as much time as is needed to complete the longer task? It seems almost like it isn't firing task2 until task1 is finished, but I know from TestConcurrent that that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: _"Perform I/O"_ Are the tasks performing IO on the same device?

Comment: You need to include the actual I/O as well. Are they using a shared component? Is there a thread sync issue? And is .Result modifying the behavior of the SynchronizationContext?

Comment: Rather than scheduling thread pool threads to sit around doing nothing while you synchronously block on asynchronous IO operations, you should instead *use inherently asynchronous IO operations* without blocking on them and wasting the thread pool's resources.

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce this with a simple Thread.Sleep in each worker task, which again leads me to think you have thread contention in the I/O itself.

Comment: Updated the question. I'm new to asynchronous computing, so while I understand the words you guys are using, and have read several blog posts by Eric Lippert and Stephen Cleary surrounding async and await, I haven't been able to wrap my head around them, so I figured until I get smarter I'll just run concurrent tasks.

Comment: "will take about 1 second, despite 2 seconds of tasks being run." - this is not exactly true - Run simply schedules work on the thread pool and *does not* guarantee that tasks will be scheduled in parallel. While I expect that you know this already, I decided to call it out for future readers of the post.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Strictly speaking, the tasks aren't performing I/O at all, but they're performing expensive manipulation of byte arrays loaded from memory. What is confined to the tasks comprises more than 90% of the function's run time.

Comment: I would try moving the `CustomArchive` constructors into the tasks. Perhaps the ctors are taking most of the time, and they are on the main thread.

Comment: And another side comment: trying to run async code in a constructor is a huge mess; using `.Wait()` or  `.Result` may cause deadlocks - rewriting the sample code without these problems would be nice.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Good idea, but moving the CustomArchive ctors into the Tasks didn't change the benchmark time at all. If anything, it got a little slower, but that was almost assuredly due to processor fluctuations. @Alexei Does it change much about it being "a mess" that the ctor is going to be private, and will only be callable through a `return await Task.Run(() => new TestObject(path));` static method? It's my understanding that that wouldn't deadlock anything, and, in practice, even the current code never deadlocks, it's just slower than expected.